# Wrong emoji showing after SWITCH statement in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, emoji

I just started adding emojis to one of my reports. I wanted to add a simple semaphore field. I created 2 columns to test how it looked with two styles, squares and circles. Additionally I added a warning sign emoji, a checkmark emoji and a cross emoji for erroneous values, success and fail, respectively. These are the specific emojis I am using:

Fail: ❌

Red:  /

Yellow:  /

Green:  /

Success: ✔ / ✅

Error: ⚠

The following explanation might be confusing, I hope it's understandable enough. So, I was leaning towards using the square emojis. The circular emojis work fine, but I have a problem where when I replace the ✔ for a ✅ in my code, the table shows the green checkmark where the ❌ should appear, as it does with the circular emojis. If I add a space in front of the checkmark ie. " ✅", it works as it should, but if I then put the code inside a TRIM(), the ✅ comes back again instead of ❌. It happens even if I declare a variable that figures out which emoji to use and **after that** in the RETURN statement I put the variable inside a TRIM(). Furthermore, I started testing stuff and I noticed that if I replace , , , , , or  with ✅, I also get ❌ (I'm assuming the same would happen with ⚠). If I replace ❌ with ✅ I also get ✅. Puzzlingly, if I replace ❌ with ✅ and I replace ✅, ❌, , , or , it now shows ✅ where the respective other emojis should now appear.

My code is pretty straightforward, as follows:

```
advertencia_semaforo_circulo = 

VAR cruz     = -2
VAR rojo     = -1
VAR amarillo =  0
VAR verde    =  1
VAR check    =  2
VAR err      = -99

VAR emoji =

SWITCH(memorias[advertencia_codigo] , 
cruz     , "❌" ,  
rojo     , "" , 
amarillo , "" , 
verde    , "" ,  
check    , "✔" , 
err      , "⚠"  ,
           "⚠"
)

RETURN emoji
```

and

```
advertencia_semaforo_cuadrado = 

VAR cruz     = -2
VAR rojo     = -1
VAR amarillo =  0
VAR verde    =  1
VAR check    =  2
VAR err      = -99

VAR emoji = 

SWITCH(memorias[advertencia_codigo] , 
cruz     , "❌" ,  
rojo     , "" , 
amarillo , "" , 
verde    , "" ,  
check    , "✅" , 
err      , "⚠"  , 
           "⚠"
)

RETURN emoji
```

This results in the following:

[image: tableA]

...

[image: tableB]

If I add a space in front of the ✅ as in here:

```
IF(check    , " ✅" ,
```

that yields the following:

[image: tableC]

but if I now do TRIM

```
RETURN TRIM(emoji)
```

it reverts to the previous erroneous result. I can live with either the extra space or the black checkmark, but I'd prefer the square checkmark with no space inserted. Plus, it's very puzzling to me that this happens and I'd like to understand why that is.

---

PS:

I tried using the corresponding UNICHAR codes as suggested in an answer, but that didn't fix the issue. Specifically, this code was as follows:

```
SWITCH(memorias[advertencia_codigo] , 
cruz     , UNICHAR(10060)  ,  
rojo     , UNICHAR(128997) , 
amarillo , UNICHAR(129000) , 
verde    , UNICHAR(129001) ,  
check    , UNICHAR(9989)   , 
err      , UNICHAR(9888)   ,
           UNICHAR(9888)
)
```

---

**Edit:** I noticed that cruz = -2 while check = 2, so I thought maybe the problem was somehow related to it being the same number just with a different sight. So I changed cruz to be -3, -30 and 30, but there was no effect on the result.

**Edit 2:** I added a suggestion I tried which didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
advertencia_semaforo_cuadrado = 

VAR cruz     = -2
VAR rojo     = -1
VAR amarillo =  0
VAR verde    =  1
VAR check    =  2
VAR err      = -99

VAR emoji = 

SWITCH(memorias[advertencia_codigo] , 
cruz     , UNICHAR(10060) ,  
rojo     , UNICHAR(128997) , 
amarillo , UNICHAR(129000) , 
verde    , UNICHAR(129001) ,  
check    , UNICHAR(9989) , 
err      , UNICHAR(9888)  ,
           UNICHAR(9888)
)

RETURN emoji
```

Instead of using the emoji, you are using the Unichar code. Maybe this will work?

**EDIT** 
The solution above doesn't work. The only workaround I could find is using ✔️ instead of ✅.

Comment: Nope, I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Could you provide me with a .pbix sample file?

Comment: Sure: [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/819mknz2977lu7y/Prueba%20limpia%20-%20copia.pbix?dl=0). It's in the table 'memorias'. memorias[advertencia_codigo] works fine, as does memorias[advertencia_semaforo_circulo]. Only memorias[advertencia_semaforo_cuadrado] has this weird behavior. As far as I've tested, only the ✅ emoji causes it, from the ones I use.

Comment: I missed mentioning I'm currently testing this in the page 'Profesor'

Comment: Thanks. It is really strange ✅ does'nt work. The only work around I found is to use ✔️ instead of ✅. This should work.

Comment: A shame, the square emoji went so well with the others. But since the fail state emoji is not inside a square, the success state emoji not being inside a square makes it so there's a logic behind the selected icons: the actual semaphore icons are solid squares, and the fail/success/error icons aren't. I think ✔️ will work nicely. I'm still mystified by the weird behavior with ✅ though, would be nice to know what makes it work like that and have closure . I'll report it as a possible bug then. Much appreciated. You can add this alternative to your answer and then I'll accept it. Many thanks!